# Data preparation for EOF Analysis in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am pretty much new to RStudio, I am DOING EOF Analysis in RStudio on time series data, and I have my data in CSV format, can someone please guide or refer me to the literature on how can I use this data in R for EOF Analysis or what changes are required in data?

Answer (score 1):

A brief google search could really help you just by including "in R" will show lots of possible literature. For starters, some of the results are [metR package](https://eliocamp.github.io/metR/index.html) and [wql package](https://github.com/jsta/wql). Read through the website and run some of the provided examples to get some practice on using RStudio.

Another approach would be to look for similar Open Source research articles that provide their R Code openly for reproducibility or if you are lucky enough, look for a book about EOF that has R implementation.